# Does Chrome manage setInterval throttling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I'm using Canvas in html5 with EaselJS, and after playing with the interface for a while, the timer events in Easel started firing really slowly. These timer events should have been running at 20Hz, but were instead running at 1Hz. The odd part was I commented out the '_testMouseOver' [function](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/files/easeljs_display_Stage.js.html) in easel, and the timer still ran slowly some of the time.

Things got weirder when I loaded the page and set up a console log in the _testMouseOver function. Sometimes it would run at 20Hz, printing out many statements, but other times it would run at 1Hz. The crazy part was: when I scrolled down on the page (not on the canvas), the timer returned to 20Hz!

This behavior remained when I commented out _testMouseOver, so that basically setInterval(fun, 50) was running 'fun' at 1Hz. This was reproduced roughly 50% of the time I refreshed the page. I also checked the cpu load via Activity Monitor and Chrome was only taking 10%.

Whats really strange is that when I closed that tab and opened a new one with the same page, the behavior disappeared.

What could have happened, and what other debugging steps might you explore?

Other details:
Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)
OSX 10.10.5